# What does SharePoint retrieve from the server if a page is empty

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a Site Collection whose site and all subsites are either extremely slow or not being loaded at all.  I am being told my site is corrupted and I need to revert to a backed up copy of the site.  For kicks when the site did come up for a few minutes I changed the home page to nothing other than the text "Home".  Sure enough 20 minutes later our sites including the site who's page I had just changed did not load.

Isn't this an issue that SP is unable to connect to the server ? I am being told there is probably some bad css or js somewhere, but if I strip the home page to just "Home" and out of the box "seattle" page how can this be a corruption issue ?

Comment: this thing required more efforts, checking the ULS logs and event to get some clue why it is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears CPU was at 100%.  Once they cleared the Proc Cache all was fine...Am curious to know though what caused the high usage.